# Why "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: null is not a function" while using AdyenCheckout in my angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, adyen

In my angular app, I'm using AdyenCheckout for payment, But once I open my screen where I'm using AdyenCheckout (Payment screen), I'm getting a console error repeatedly when I move my cursor

"Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: null is not a function"

Following is my package.json

```
"@adyen/adyen-web": "^4.5.0",
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
"@angular/animations": "8.2.13",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/cli": "8.3.17",
"@angular/common": "8.2.13",
"@angular/compiler": "8.2.13",
"@angular/core": "8.2.13",
"@angular/forms": "8.2.13",
"@angular/material": "8.1.1",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "8.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.13",
"@angular/router": "8.2.13",
```

Checkout code

```
const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
```

[image]

Comment: This has been already raised as Github issue https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-web/issues/1482 and is being investigated. Just checking: would you be able to upgrade the adyen-web version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

upgrade version to "@adyen/adyen-web": "5.5.0",

```
 const checkout = await AdyenCheckout(configuration);
```

Comment: Did it fix the problem?

Comment: @BeppeC This fixed that bug

Comment: Great to hear it, thanks for confirming

Comment: @Ajith if the problem is indeed fixed, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks!